# how to include a bootstrap plugin(input spinner) present in node module folder inside a html file.?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, npm-install

1. In my project I want to include a (input-spinner ) in my HTML file.
2. I run the npm install bootstrap-input-spinner command.
3. A node module folder and package lock.json was created along with my HTML file
4. In HTML, I created a link for that plugin but this is not working.

My HTML body code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1> Calculator</h1>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
      <script src="/node_modules/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>
      <script>
           $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
      </script>
</body>
```

I also include bootstrap cdn in my project

Answer (score 0):

your script tag should look like this:

```
<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap-input-spinner/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>
```